How to force formulas to the left edge (border) in LaTex?
How to force formulas to the left edge (border) in LaTex? I mean that if you write formulas that do not fit into the allowed writing field, they are still visible until they "cross" the sheet border. For this, I need to move the allowed left border so that the formulas still fit the page widthwise. I understand that this is not a good thing to do, but I reduced the font to the minimum (\tiny), and the formulas still did not fit. I do not consider the option of moving the formulas to another slide. I need them to fit on exactly one slide.
\begin{frame}
        \noindent\vspace{-13pt}\tiny{
            \begin{align*}
                &A_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad  A_{02}=\frac{a^{2}b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad
                C_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}J_{0}}{a^{2}},\quad
                C_{02}=-b^{2}J_{0},\quad A_{13}=-\frac{b(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{n1}=-\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}\kappa^{2}(1+n)(GJ_{2}(-2+n)-K_{1}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n3}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(2+\kappa)b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ_{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+2n}(-2+\kappa n)(-a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(a(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(1+n)-b^{2}(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n1}=\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}(1+n)(GJ1(n-2)+K_{2}n)a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(n+2))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(n+1)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(-1+n)+b^{2}(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n3}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{2+n}(b^{2+2n}\kappa(2+\kappa)(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa^{2}(-1+n)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}+(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2})+4a^{2}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2})},\\
                &B_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+n}(-2+\kappa n)(a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(1+n)+b^{2}(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{11}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{3}(b^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa^{2}+a^{2}(\kappa+2)(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{13}=\frac{b(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{12}=\frac{b(\frac{\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(-2+\kappa)+b^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{12}-K_{11}+2GJ_{12}\kappa))}{b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa)}+2(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)\ln a)}{8G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{14}=-\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(-a^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+b^{2}(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{11}=\frac{a^{2}b^{5}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa^{2}+a^{4}b^{3}(2+\kappa)(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+2J_{11}\kappa))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
                &B_{12}=-\frac{(b(\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{11}+K_{12}+2GJ_{11}\kappa))+2(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))\ln a))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
                &B_{14}=\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(a^{2}(-GJ_{11}+K_{12})\kappa+b^{2}(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+J_{11}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))}.
        \end{align*}}
    \end{frame}




Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

Display math is in vmode, so you would need a minipage or \parbox with a larger width.   A common approach to overlapping the margins is to use \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{...}.  You might also want to use a trivlist to handle the transition from text to math.

If you are using beamer, as your tags suggest, then you could use columns to temporarily disable margins

... and if you are using beamer, then \tiny isn't the minimum, there is still \Tiny below that (but you shouldn't use it for actual content, unless you speak at a congress for ophthalmologists)

What font size is there between \tiny and \Tiny?

@Mark an infinity of sizes.  Please update your question

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is this meant to be a practical joke? Or do you want to be remembered as the person who created the most-overcrowded-slide-of-the-year?

@Mark Why do you want to create a slide like this? It is not a good idea to fill a slide with long and complicated formulae.

have you considered using a handout instead for this material? unless, of course, the purpose is to avoid scrutiny, which is really the only reason I can think for doing this. if you put stuff on a handout, you can split material between slides and still have people able to see the entire block. you can even do this using a single frame straight from beamer i.e. you don't need a separate document or to have two versions of anything.

I don't recommend this layout, however the following code would theoretically fit them on the frame. The columns environment temporarily disables the normal text margins and the shrink option will make the text even tinier so that it fits on the frame.
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=12]
\vskip-10pt
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{\paperwidth}
\tiny
\begin{align*}
                &A_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad  A_{02}=\frac{a^{2}b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad
                C_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}J_{0}}{a^{2}},\quad
                C_{02}=-b^{2}J_{0},\quad A_{13}=-\frac{b(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{n1}=-\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}\kappa^{2}(1+n)(GJ_{2}(-2+n)-K_{1}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n3}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(2+\kappa)b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ_{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+2n}(-2+\kappa n)(-a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(a(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(1+n)-b^{2}(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n1}=\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}(1+n)(GJ1(n-2)+K_{2}n)a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(n+2))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(n+1)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(-1+n)+b^{2}(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n3}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{2+n}(b^{2+2n}\kappa(2+\kappa)(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa^{2}(-1+n)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}+(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2})+4a^{2}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2})},\\
                &B_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+n}(-2+\kappa n)(a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(1+n)+b^{2}(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{11}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{3}(b^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa^{2}+a^{2}(\kappa+2)(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{13}=\frac{b(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{12}=\frac{b(\frac{\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(-2+\kappa)+b^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{12}-K_{11}+2GJ_{12}\kappa))}{b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa)}+2(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)\ln a)}{8G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{14}=-\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(-a^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+b^{2}(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{11}=\frac{a^{2}b^{5}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa^{2}+a^{4}b^{3}(2+\kappa)(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+2J_{11}\kappa))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
                &B_{12}=-\frac{(b(\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{11}+K_{12}+2GJ_{11}\kappa))+2(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))\ln a))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
                &B_{14}=\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(a^{2}(-GJ_{11}+K_{12})\kappa+b^{2}(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+J_{11}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))}.
        \end{align*}
\end{column}
\end{columns}           
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Are you sure the + on line 8 shouldn't be a - ?

@DavidCarlisle It gets compensated by the symmetrically defined coefficient in line 42 :P

@DavidCarlisle it will all make sense once the footnotes are added.

I suggest you reduce the values of the low-level length parameters \thinmuskip, \medmuskip, and \thickmuskip, which govern the spacing around objects of type mathop, mathbin, and mathrel. That way, there's less of a need for shrink.
Oh, and unless you absolutely hate your readers, do consider replacing some of the outermost round parentheses in each numerator and denominator with square brackets.

\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=18] % '18' determined by trial-and-error
\thinmuskip=1mu          % default: 3mu
\medmuskip=1mu           % default: 4mu
\thickmuskip=1mu         % default: 5mu
\tiny

\begin{align*}
&A_{01}=-\frac{b^2K_0}{G(a^2+b^2\kappa)}
\qquad A_{02}=\frac{a^2b^2K_0}{G(a^2+b^2\kappa)}
\qquad C_{01}=-\frac{b^2J_0}{a^2}
\qquad C_{02}=-b^2J_0
\qquad A_{13}=-\frac{b(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)}\\
&A_{n1}=-\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}[-b^{2+2n}\kappa^2(1+n)(GJ_2(-2+n)-K_1n)+a^{2n}b^2\kappa(\kappa+2)(K_1n+GJ_2(2+n))+a^2b^{2n}(GJ_2-K_1)(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^2))]}{4G(1+n)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^2b^2\kappa^2+4a^4(1+\kappa)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2)]}\\
&A_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)[a^{2+2n}(GJ_2+K_1)(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(a^2(GJ_2-K_1)(-1+n)+b^2(-GJ{2}(-2+n)+K_1n))]}{4G(-1+n)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^2b^2\kappa^2+4a^4(1+\kappa)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2)]}\\
&A_{n3}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)[a^{2+2n}(GJ_2+K_1)(2+\kappa)b^{2n}\kappa(a^2(GJ_2-K_1)(-1+n)+b^2(-GJ_2(-2+n)+K_1n))]}{4G(-1+n)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^2b^2\kappa^2+4a^4(1+\kappa)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2)]}\\
&A_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+2n}(-2+\kappa n)[-a^2b^{2n}(GJ_2-K_1)(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(a(GJ_2+K_1)(1+n)-b^2(K_1n+GJ_2(2+n)))]}{4G(1+n)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^2b^2\kappa^2+4a^4(1+\kappa)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2)]}\\
&B_{n1}=\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}[-b^{2+2n}(1+n)(GJ1(n-2)+K_2n)a^{2n}b^2\kappa(\kappa+2)(-K_2n+GJ_1(n+2))+a^2b^{2n}(GJ_1+K_2)(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^2))]}{4G(n+1)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^2b^2\kappa^2+4a^4(\kappa+1)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2)]}\\
&B_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)[-a^{2+2n}(GJ_1-K_2)(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(-a^2(GJ_1+K_2)(-1+n)+b^2(GJ_1(-2+n)+K_2n))]}{4G(-1+n)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^2b^2\kappa^2+4a^4(\kappa+1)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2)]}\\
&B_{n3}=-\frac{a^2b^{2+n}[b^{2+2n}\kappa(2+\kappa)(GJ_1(-2+n)+K_2n)+a^{2n}b^2\kappa^2(-1+n)(-K_2n+GJ_1(2+n))-a^{2+2n}(GJ_1-K_2)(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^2))]}{4G(-1+n)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}+(2a^2b^2\kappa^2)+4a^2(\kappa+1)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2]}\\
&B_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+n}(-2+\kappa n)[a^2b^{2n}(GJ_1+K_2)(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(-a^2(GJ_1-K_2)(1+n)+b^2(-K_2n+GJ_1(2+n)))]}{4G(1+n)[a^{2+4n}b^2\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^2b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^2b^2\kappa^2+4a^4(\kappa+1)+(a^2-b^2)^2\kappa^2n^2)]}\\
&A_{11}=-\frac{a^2b^{3}[b^2(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa^2+a^2(\kappa+2)(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa))]}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^4\kappa+a^4(2+\kappa))}
\qquad B_{13}=\frac{b(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)}\\
&A_{12}=\frac{b\Bigl[\frac{\kappa[-a^4(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(-2+\kappa)+b^4(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+2a^2b^2(GJ_{12}-K_{11}+2GJ_{12}\kappa)]}{b^4\kappa+a^4(2+\kappa)}+2(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)\ln a\Bigr]}{8G(1+\kappa)}\\
&A_{14}=-\frac{b(-2+\kappa)[-a^2(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+b^2(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa))]}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^4\kappa+a^4(2+\kappa))}
\qquad B_{11}=\frac{a^2b^{5}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa^2+a^4b^{3}(2+\kappa)(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+2J_{11}\kappa))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^4\kappa+a^4(2+\kappa))}\\
&B_{12}=-\frac{b[\kappa(-a^4(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa+2a^2b^2(GJ_{11}+K_{12}+2GJ_{11}\kappa))+2(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)(b^4\kappa+a^4(2+\kappa))\ln a]}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^4\kappa+a^4(2+\kappa))}\\
&B_{14}=\frac{b(-2+\kappa)[a^2(-GJ_{11}+K_{12})\kappa+b^2(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+J_{11}\kappa))]}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^4\kappa+a^4(2+\kappa))}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}


Just a small detail: beamer expects a percentage for the shrink option, not a length.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Good catch! Fixed now.

Even better would be something closer to the actually used value, e.g. 18. The closer the value is to the used value, the better beamer can calculate the width of the frame.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - Thanks for the follow-up. Fixed 'shrink' factor.

Much better! Thanks!

This is not the recommended approach, but I thought it'd be fun to do with \pgflowlevelsynccm, which lets you scale letters in nodes.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.5,xshift=10cm]
\pgflowlevelsynccm
\node (X) {$\begin{aligned}
    &A_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad  A_{02}=\frac{a^{2}b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad
    C_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}J_{0}}{a^{2}},\quad
    C_{02}=-b^{2}J_{0},\quad A_{13}=-\frac{b(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
    &A_{n1}=-\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}\kappa^{2}(1+n)(GJ_{2}(-2+n)-K_{1}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
    &A_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
    &A_{n3}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(2+\kappa)b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ_{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
    &A_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+2n}(-2+\kappa n)(-a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(a(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(1+n)-b^{2}(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
    &B_{n1}=\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}(1+n)(GJ1(n-2)+K_{2}n)a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(n+2))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(n+1)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
    &B_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(-1+n)+b^{2}(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
    &B_{n3}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{2+n}(b^{2+2n}\kappa(2+\kappa)(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa^{2}(-1+n)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}+(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2})+4a^{2}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2})},\\
    &B_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+n}(-2+\kappa n)(a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(1+n)+b^{2}(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
    &A_{11}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{3}(b^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa^{2}+a^{2}(\kappa+2)(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{13}=\frac{b(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
    &A_{12}=\frac{b(\frac{\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(-2+\kappa)+b^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{12}-K_{11}+2GJ_{12}\kappa))}{b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa)}+2(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)\ln a)}{8G(1+\kappa)},\\
    &A_{14}=-\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(-a^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+b^{2}(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{11}=\frac{a^{2}b^{5}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa^{2}+a^{4}b^{3}(2+\kappa)(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+2J_{11}\kappa))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
    &B_{12}=-\frac{(b(\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{11}+K_{12}+2GJ_{11}\kappa))+2(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))\ln a))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
    &B_{14}=\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(a^{2}(-GJ_{11}+K_{12})\kappa+b^{2}(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+J_{11}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))}.
\end{aligned}$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



You can encapsulate your material into \centerline\vbox{...}}. The \centerline macro is defined by
\long\def\centerline#1{\hbox to\hsize{\hss#1\hss}}

It means that the material will be at the center of the page and it can go over the edges symmetrically to both sides.
\begin{frame}[shrink=12]
\centerline{\vbox{
        \noindent\vspace{-13pt}\tiny{
            \begin{align*}
                &A_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad  A_{02}=\frac{a^{2}b^{2}K_{0}}{G(a^{2}+b^{2}\kappa)},\quad
                C_{01}=-\frac{b^{2}J_{0}}{a^{2}},\quad
                C_{02}=-b^{2}J_{0},\quad A_{13}=-\frac{b(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{n1}=-\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}\kappa^{2}(1+n)(GJ_{2}(-2+n)-K_{1}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n3}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(a^{2+2n}(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(2+\kappa)b^{2n}\kappa(a^{2}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(-1+n)+b^{2}(-GJ_{2}(-2+n)+K_{1}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+2n}(-2+\kappa n)(-a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{2}-K_{1})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(a(GJ_{2}+K_{1})(1+n)-b^{2}(K_{1}n+GJ_{2}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(1+\kappa)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n1}=\frac{a^{2+2n}b^{2+n}(-b^{2+2n}(1+n)(GJ1(n-2)+K_{2}n)a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(n+2))+a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(n+1)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n2}=\frac{a^{2n}b^{2+n}(2+\kappa n)(-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(\kappa+2)+b^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(-1+n)+b^{2}(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &B_{n3}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{2+n}(b^{2+2n}\kappa(2+\kappa)(GJ_{1}(-2+n)+K_{2}n)+a^{2n}b^{2}\kappa^{2}(-1+n)(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))-a^{2+2n}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(4+\kappa(4+\kappa n^{2})))}{4G(-1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}+(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2})+4a^{2}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2})},\\
                &B_{n4}=\frac{b^{2+n}(-2+\kappa n)(a^{2}b^{2n}(GJ_{1}+K_{2})(2+\kappa)+a^{2n}\kappa(-a^{2}(GJ_{1}-K_{2})(1+n)+b^{2}(-K_{2}n+GJ_{1}(2+n))))}{4G(1+n)(a^{2+4n}b^{2}\kappa(2+\kappa)+a^{2}b^{2+4n}\kappa(\kappa+2)+a^{2n}b^{2n}(2a^{2}b^{2}\kappa^{2}+4a^{4}(\kappa+1)+(a^{2}-b^{2})^{2}\kappa^{2}n^{2}))},\\
                &A_{11}=-\frac{a^{2}b^{3}(b^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa^{2}+a^{2}(\kappa+2)(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{13}=\frac{b(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)}{4G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{12}=\frac{b(\frac{\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(-2+\kappa)+b^{4}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{12}-K_{11}+2GJ_{12}\kappa))}{b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa)}+2(GJ_{12}+K_{11})(2+\kappa)\ln a)}{8G(1+\kappa)},\\
                &A_{14}=-\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(-a^{2}(GJ_{12}+K_{11})\kappa+b^{2}(-K_{11}+G(J_{12}+2J_{12}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\quad B_{11}=\frac{a^{2}b^{5}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa^{2}+a^{4}b^{3}(2+\kappa)(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+2J_{11}\kappa))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
                &B_{12}=-\frac{(b(\kappa(-a^{4}(GJ_{11}-K_{12})\kappa+2a^{2}b^{2}(GJ_{11}+K_{12}+2GJ_{11}\kappa))+2(GJ_{11}-K_{12})(2+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))\ln a))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))},\\
                &B_{14}=\frac{b(-2+\kappa)(a^{2}(-GJ_{11}+K_{12})\kappa+b^{2}(K_{12}+G(J_{11}+J_{11}\kappa)))}{8G(1+\kappa)(b^{4}\kappa+a^{4}(2+\kappa))}.
        \end{align*}}
}}
\end{frame}


\tiny is a switch and does not take a brace-delimited argument.

@Mico I just copied that latex garbage presented by OP and added \centerline. In fact, one irrelevant group in addition may not matter.

I know. But something it's the small and almost irrelevant stuff that catches one's attention. :-). My personal view is that this mess of a slide shouldn't be taken seriously.
